# Quick way of copying a set of private variables into corresponding Public ReadOnly Properties?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of private variables I've typed out and I want to put all of my corresponding Public ReadOnly Properties in a bunch below them.

Is there some way of copying ten lines of

```
Private _myVar As String
```

and pasting in ten sets of

```
Public Readonly Property MyVar As String
    Get
        Return _myVar
    End Get
End Property
```

I'm currently copying the whole bunch of variable declarations, Find+Replacing `Private _` into `Public ReadOnly Property` then going line-by-line expanding the definitions and writing return statements.

It's pretty much too late for me now, but I would like to know how to avoid all this nonsense in the future, as I'm developing on a virtual terminal server, and the input lag on my little copy/paste/type operations on the code is driving me up the wall.

Comment: Have you thought about using code snippets?

Comment: I know this is a singularly unhelpful comment, but if you really **would like to know how to avoid all this nonsense in the future** . . . write your .net code in C# `public string MyVar {get; private set}` and you're done. At work we have lots of Vb.Net code, and I have to say while I generally dislike it's verbosity, I find writing classes with lots of properties _absolutely soul destroying_

Comment: @Binary Worrier: Ugh. I am entirely over VB at this point. I liked its verbosity when I first started in the industry because it levelled out my mental peaks and troughs somewhat while I was writing, and five years ago there were still some hold-outs keeping the VB community alive, but it's a dreadful little ghetto language at this point and I'm trying to claw my way out. Right at the moment, though, I'm just trying to find better ways of overcoming this damnable terminal server input lag...

Comment: @PVitt: As I understand it, code snippets would help me to put varable declarations next to my readonly properties. That's not what I'm looking for; I want a bunch of variables, then a bunch of properties, separately. If there's a way to use code snippets for this, feel free to educate me.

Comment: In C#, the code snippet is called "propg". This leads to a Property with getter and a private backing field. But I don't know how this is called in VB.NET. To have them seperated you can use Regionerate, an VS Addon that sorts your code files following patterns you describe in a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress Refactor! can take fields and convert them in to properties like you want.